# Ranking a person based of COUNT using RANKX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure, to get the rank of a person's apperances. In power bi.

```
Table T

Person  Location  
P1        L1     
P1        L2
P2        L1
P2        L2
P2        L3
```

P1 would get rank 2, and P2 rank 1. I've tried the following DAX function, but it gives me Rank 1 for both.

```
Ranked = RANKX(T; COUNT(T[Person]);;ASC)
```

I haven't done much in DAX before, and sorry if this is too simple for a question.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple report in Power BI Desktop to show one way this problem can be approached.  You may download it from here:

[demo file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4zxevyxle87qde7/stack%20overflow%20-%20rank%20persons.pbix)

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful

For anyone else's reference DAX0110 counted location with: Count Locations = COUNT(T[Location])

and then calculated rank with:
Rank = VAR thisCount = [Count Locations]
RETURN
 CALCULATE(
  RANKX(
   VALUES(T[Person])
   , CALCULATE(COUNT(T[Location]))
   , thisCount
   , DESC
  )
  , ALLSELECTED(T)
 )